# Regex: Is it possible to do a substitution within a capture group?

Tags: json, regex, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I have this one line JSON text:

```
{"schemaText":{"fields":[{"name":"AX_SND_TYPE","type":"string"},{"name":"BWORK","type":"int"}],"name":"XXXSchema","type":"record"},"description":"Autogenerated by NiFi"}
```

As can be seen there is a  property called "schemaText" that contains an object, I want to convert it to a string, so the 'only' thing I need to do is add quotes at the beginning and end of the property and escape the quotes inside.

Using the regular expression bellow (not that my regex knowledge is really low), I am able to do the first step:

```
({"schemaText":)(\{"fields":\[.*)(,"description.*)
```

Using the substitution

```
$1"$2"$3
```

gives the result:

```
{"schemaText":"{"fields":[{"name":"AX_SND_TYPE","type":"string"},{"name":"BWORK","type":"int"}],"name":"XXXSchema","type":"record"}","description":"Autogenerated by NiFi"}
```

But still remains to escape the quotes to get this:

```
{"schemaText":"{\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"AX_SND_TYPE\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"BWORK\",\"type\":\"int\"}],"name":"XXXSchema","type":"record"}","description":"Autogenerated by NiFi"}
```

That is have valid JSON format.

The question is: is there a way to escape the quotes inside $2 capture group in the same regular expression?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have to use regex for this? Can you not use a JSON parser to stringify/objectify the different parts as you wish?

Comment: Yes, only regex, currently I have a code approach, but the point is solve it only using with regex, if possible.

Comment: Regex won't escape strings for you. You would need substitutions for the backslashes

Comment: @cricket-007 Not really sure if you read and understand your point, what must be escaped are the quotes of the property  schemaText, to be able to POST it to schema registry, escape all the quotes with regex is trivial like in this example: https://regex101.com/r/QNtqYy/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is no, it's not possible. You're really trying to do two different, unrelated substitutions in a single regular expression. This is a feature that no regular expression engine supports.

Think about it: Your first requirement is for the engine to perform a substitution on the whole text (the quotes), and then, for your second requirement, the engine has to somehow backtrack and perform more substitutions on text which may or may not have already changed: e.g.: It would need to perform a new match on the already substituted text, which, depending on what the first substitution did, may not even exist anymore!

If, as you say, you already have an aproach that works, keep that. A single regular expression is simply not a good fit for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry but this is not entirely true, as I wrote, the quotes must be substituted only inside the the capture group, in fact the question is: it's possible to perform a substitution inside a capture group?

Comment: @ÓscarAndreu I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. By trying t constrain the substitution in this way, what you're really doing is what I described. We tend to think regular expressions are really complex software, but the truth is they aren't, and they have some caveats. One of them is that a regex engine is *single-pass*: except for lookaheads and lookbehinds, which are not really matches and can't be captured, the regex engine always reads from left to right and never backtracks.

Comment: A substitution means: delete all the matched text, and paste this in its place. When the substitution is inserted, there's no turning back. To somehow replace the text that was generated by the `$2` reference, the engine would have to backtrack on the replaced text, which would require a new match. I'm asserting to you the engine doesn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend tackling this problem using code e.g. with vanilla JavaScript:

```
let json = '{"schemaText":{"fields":[{"name":"AX_SND_TYPE","type":"string"},{"name":"BWORK","type":"int"}],"name":"XXXSchema","type":"record"},"description":"Autogenerated by NiFi"}';

let obj = JSON.parse(json);
let schemaTextAsString = JSON.stringify(obj.schemaText)
obj.schemaText = schemaTextAsString

var result = JSON.stringify(obj)
```

You can see this working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Fresh/t31068gz/).

Note that in your desired output you were not escaping the quotes in schemaText's name field, but this code does.

Finally whenever I use regular expressions I always think of this classic article ["Regular Expressions: Now You Have Two Problems"](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)!

Comment: Ah, I can see you are using Avro which doesn't support javascript "out of the box".  I can see that there is a JS client for it though https://github.com/mtth/avsc. If this answer is not relevant for you I'd still recommend tackling this problem using a similar approach rather than pure regex.

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for your reponse. I am currently using javascript as you did to manage the problem, but the question is if is possible to do a substitution inside a capture group, only regex.

Answer (score 1):

Just for your information, you can actually *match* at every position where a substitution should occur, using an expression such as the following:

```
/({"schemaText":)|}(,"description")(.*)|([^"]*)"/g
```

The only issue, as others have mentioned, is that you want to do more than match; you want to perform a "conditional replacement" because there does not exist a single catch-all substitution that will cover all 3 cases you're dealing with (insert starting `"`, insert `\` before quotes, and insert ending `"`).

You can in fact accomplish this with a single replace() call:

```
var test = "{\"schemaText\":{\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"AX_SND_TYPE\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"BWORK\",\"type\":\"int\"}],\"name\":\"XXXSchema\",\"type\":\"record\"},\"description\":\"Autogenerated by NiFi\"}";
window.alert(test.replace(/({"schemaText":)|}(,"description")(.*)|([^"]*)"/g, function(a,b,c,d,e){ return (b=="{\"schemaText\":"?b+"\"":(c==",\"description\""?"}\""+c+d:e+"\\\"")) })));
```

So it's technically "the same regex", but the substitution parameter uses an inline function as replacement rather than a static string.