# RegEx: is it possible to make multiple substitutions within a larger capture group?

Tags: regex, pcre2

I need to transform survey results from a comma-separated variable file (originally Excel) where each of the few hundred records contains an arbitrary number of quotes about a location (preceded by "Story xx: " and followed by a new line) to a JSON file that I can use as the data source for a website that will map the responses. A typical record looks like this (I had to remove some URLs or the post was flagged as spam):

```
1,Alethia Tanner Park,227 Harry Thomas Way NE,Washington,DC,20002,3,"Story 1: First quote of someone commenting on this location.
Story 2: Second quote from a resident that likes this place.
Story 3: Third quote about this park in the city.







",38.91143761,-77.00165721
```

I want to transform the above to this where each quote is surrounded by HTML left/right double quotes and followed by a horizontal line:

```
{
    "latitudeLongitude": [38.91143761, -77.00165721], 
    "displayName": "Alethia Tanner Park", 
    "quote": "&ldquo;First quote of someone commenting on this location.&rdquo;<hr />&ldquo;Second quote from a resident that likes this place.&rdquo;<hr />&ldquo;Third quote about this park in the city.&rdquo;<hr />", 
    "numberOfCitations": 3
},
```

I am using regex101.com (which uses PCRE2 processor by default) and my input regular expression to extract the components of each record is:

```
^(?'groupId'[0-9]{1,3}),(?'displayName'[^,]+),(?'street'\?\?\?|[0-9 a-zA-Z]*),(?'city'\?\?\?|[ a-zA-Z]*),(?'state'\?\?\?|[A-Z]{2}),(?'zipCode'\?\?\?|[0-9]{5}),(?'numberOfCitations'[0-9]{1,2}),"(?:Story [0-9]{1,2}: (?'quote'[ 0-9a-zA-Z\(\)\-\+,.'&!?]*)\n)+\n*",(?'latitude'38\.[0-9]{4,8}),(?'longitude'-7[6|7]\.[0-9]{4,8})$
```

Note the part trying to capture all the individual quotes inside the string with a plus sign outside the group to indicate there is at least one:

```
"(?:Story [0-9]{1,2}: (?'quote'[ 0-9a-zA-Z\(\)\-\+,.'&!?]*)\n)+\n*"
```

My substitution is

```
{\n\t"latitudeLongitude": [${latitude}, ${longitude}], \n\t"displayName": "${displayName}", \n\t"quote": "(&ldquo;${quote}&rdquo;<hr />)+", \n\t"numberOfCitations": ${numberOfCitations}\n},
```

but I capture only the last of the three quotes so the output is

```
{
    "latitudeLongitude": [38.91143761, -77.00165721], 
    "displayName": "Alethia Tanner Park", 
    "quote": "&ldquo;Third quote about this park in the city.&rdquo;<hr />", 
    "numberOfCitations": 3
},
```

I hoped that adding parentheses and a plus sign `(&ldquo;${quote}&rdquo;<hr />)+` to indicate multiple instances would work but clearly it does not as they just appear in the output as you cn see here https://regex101.com/r/pYaN92/1.

Is there a way to capture all the quotes and process them? I can achieve what I need by processing the quotes separately but I am curious to know if what I want to achieve is possible in a single pass.This post ([Regex: Is it possible to do a substitution within a capture group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52292155/regex-is-it-possible-to-do-a-substitution-within-a-capture-group)) suggests not but that is somewhat different as he is trying to match just on quote marks which exist elsewhere; I have a match on a "quote" within the overall capture but only one is processed.

Comment: You can't do this easily with a textual substitution. But most programming languages allow you to provide a function as the replacement. This can perform nested replacements in the capture groups. What language are you using?

Comment: @barmar Thank you for clarifying that for me. I had come to a dead end in my own reading but figured I should ask in case I had missed something and I could learn something new. I and fairly sure that I can deal with my requirements by making two passes - one to update all the "Story xx: ... \n" and then to extract all the components.

Comment: @PeterV You might use the `\G` anchor, and in this case the lat lon will be optional. You would have to count the number of quotes somehow https://regex101.com/r/h8Nr74/1

Comment: @The fourth bird Thank you! It is so interesting to see the changes you made- as well as the \G, also wrapping everything before the section of interest in a non-capturing group, the negative lookahead (which I need to read up about and also not needing to escape characters such as the question mark inside square brackets which I didn't realize was not required.   In any case, ${quote} then contains all three captured pieces of text so that is a win though I do need to separate them. Thank  you for showing me new things that I will investigate further.

Comment: @barmar. Sorry, I failed to answer the question of what language am I using. I am just relying on the regex101 website to make the transformation from the CSV exported from Excel to a JSON data object that is consumed by Javascript on a website I've already created in demonstration form.